# How do I view assets and layer info in Origami studio?

Tags: origami

- Following this tutorial: http://origami.design/tutorials/common-interactions/Horizontal-Scrolling.html
- Downloaded and opened the project starter file. But I don't see the layer info or the assets in the project. Below is a screenshot of what I see

[image: No layer or asset info visible]

- According to the tutorial, I should see a screen like below:

[image: The screen when all goes well]

- Not sure how to proceed, this is my first Origami studio project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a bug introduced in the most recent version of Origami. Workaround is to use an older version.

[image]